# What is the purpose of the black and white stickers on test aircraft?

Tags: flight-testing, aircraft-marking

I want to ask what is the purpose of black and white stickers used on test aircraft.

The following is a picture:

[image]

I have seen variations of such stickers. Does anyone know what is reason for their use ?

Comment: Related: [Checkerboard painted on fuselage of Boeing test aircraft](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/q/56202/1696)

Comment: Oooh, Christmas-wrapped bomb. Very festive!

Comment: Those aren't stickers, the plane just has a skin condition.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

They appear to be [fiducial markers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fiducial_marker) which identify known points on the aircraft, for analysing video footage and performing photogrammetry.

You see similar markers on crash-test dummies used in vehicle impact trials, for instance, and also in motion-capture in the synthetic movie industry (and in orthopaedics).

Comment: For the curious, the technical term for these are ["fiducial markers"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fiducial_marker). It's the same reason you find [black and white stripes and/or checkerboard patterns on some rockets](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/6352).