# What does this logo on prototype aircrafts or cars for test mean?

Tags: flight-testing, aircraft-marking

Sometimes on prototype cars or aircrafts we see a logo just like BMW logo. e.g.

[image]

[image]

Why? What does it mean? What is it for?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Checkerboard painted on fuselage of Boeing test aircraft](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/56202/checkerboard-painted-on-fuselage-of-boeing-test-aircraft) Or this? [What is the purpose of the black and white stickers on test aircraft?](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/58049/what-is-the-purpose-of-the-black-and-white-stickers-on-test-aircraft)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is simply no logo, but a reference that is both highly visible and can be measured very precisely in photos and videos - this giving a valid reference point for all measurements and analysis.