# When were checkerboard fiducial markers first used in aircraft development?

Tags: aviation-history, aircraft-development

It's common to put checkerboard [fiducial markers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fiducial_marker) on [aircraft](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/q/56202/2258) to help analyze rates and orientations from photographs and film.

[image]

**When was this practice first used on aircraft?**

Flight test versions of the German V-2 rocket were painted in a checkerboard scheme, presumably for fiducial-marking purposes (or just high visibility); was this already established practice at the time of the first V-2 test flights in 1942?

Comment: I had never noticed that on a large plane before, only on rockets. Thanks for pointing that out.

Answer (score 1):

This was not already established practice in 1942.  Not even in the early 1950's [NACA crash tests](https://www.nasa.gov/centers/glenn/about/history/crashtst.html), which were so methodical that you'd have expected these checkerboards:  seven movie cameras along the runway, a flashing light atop the fuselage for movie synchronization, a pile of onboard cameras and instruments, white paint and red-dyed fuel for better imaging.  The closest this came to checkerboards was dotted lines on the fuselage sides.

This long [NASA](https://ntrs.nasa.gov/search.jsp?R=19940029066) [video](http://youtu.be/9T0tE3xv-6I) includes many images of these aircraft.  No checkerboards anywhere.

A skim through online photos suggests that even automotive crash tests didn't start using checkerboard fiducials until the 1960's.

Comment: I think the dotted line markings are intended to serve a similar purpose, but this is good info.